# C++ bare pointer scope

Tags: c++

For raw pointer, if we don't use it to new some data, then is it ok to leave it as it is or it's better to set to NULL in c++ ? Does the physical memory for this pointer p itself(an address) get freed after function process_data get called?

```
#include<vector>

void process_data(std::vector<double> & vec)
{
double *p;
p= vec.data();

// do something with p


// do we have to set p to NULL here? 
}


int main()
{
std::vector<double> vec(10);
process_data(vec);

return;
}
```

Comment: If `p` was not a pointer, but say an ordinary `double` value, would you still be asking the same question about it? A local variable is a local variable, no matter its type, and its lifetime ends with the end of its scope (in this specific case the end of the function).

Comment: @George: That sounds like FUD and superstition. Just like not walking under ladders.

Comment: @George In fact, there are very good reasons *not* to set `p` to `nullptr`. The biggest one being that experience shows that it leads people to expect that that's either necessary or sufficient when it's neither. It's particularly bad advice to give to learners because it concretely harms their understanding and coding practice development. (I've seen more than once case where someone adding it because they thought failure to do it was a bug broke working code.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Yep, poor comment. If p has just been used to free some memory and is not about to immediately leave scope, then a fair amount of the time is a good idea to null it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to set `p` to `nullptr` (`NULL`) (or free it), because `p` doesn't own the memory it references.

`p` refers to the raw array of a `std::vector`. The `std::vector` will clean that memory up on destruction. The lifetime of that memory is the duration of `main` (`vec`).

The stack-allocated memory for `p` itself (to hold the memory address) will be cleaned up after the function returns; the function call stack unrolls after the function call completes.